# Is it possible to migrate a Google BigQuery Project or Workspace from one google Account to another? (e.g. from personal account to business)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-workspace

I have set up many tables and queries in a Google BigQuery Project/Workspace using my personal gmail account.

I just started a new business and would like to migrate that Project to my new Google business account with out having to recreate everything. Is that possible?

I see that I can move Tables and Views around to different projects withing a workspace, but do not see how to do same to a totally different google account.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- either [copy dataset with BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets) from a project to another one
- or [move (migrate) your whole project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration) from one org (or no organization if it's your personal account) to a org. *Note: if with your new business you don't have Google Cloud Organization, you simply have to grant your new email as project owner and remove the old one to transfer the ownership*